# Is it permissible to own safek Hekdesh today and use it for mitzvot?

Tags: hekdesh, meila

It is generally agreed upon that [Tyrian Half-Shekels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrian_shekel) were the only acceptable coins to pay the Half-Shekel in the times of the Second Beit HaMekdash and they were almost exclusively used in Judea. There is even archaeological debate about whether some later years were minted in Jerusalem by the Temple.

Today one can buy an authentic one, for a few hundred dollars. There is a small chance that some of these could still be Hekdesh today, looted by the Romans during the Horban and never made into hollin.

**Are there meilah issues that would arise from merely owning and displaying coins that might be Hekdesh, seeing as collecting them could be constituted as haneah?** Is this dependent on cohen status?

If they were used for a mitzvah, such as pidyon haBen, would that be a bigger issue?

Comment: Incidentally, I once saw someone do a pidyon haben with these coins. (I'm not endorsing what they did, just reporting.)

Comment: Tisch, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Great to have you learning with us. What a fascinating question.

Answer (score 4):

Bekhorot 50a

> א"ר אושעיא: ביקשו לגנוז כל כסף וזהב שבעולם מפני כספה וזהבה של ירושלים עד שמצאו לו מקרא מן התורה שהוא מותר שנאמר ובאו בה פריצים וחללוה. וירושלים הויא רובא דעלמא? אלא אמר אביי: בקשו לגנוז דינרא הדריינא טירייאנא שייאפא מפני טבעה של ירושלים עד שמצאו לה מקרא מן התורה שהוא מותר שנאמר ובאו בה פריצים וחללוה
> Rabbi Oshiya said: they sought to hide away all the silver and gold in the world because of the silver and gold of Jerusalem [which had been plundered by the Romans] until they found a verse from the Tanakh permitting it, as it says ([Ezekiel 7:22](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1207.htm#22)) 'and robbers shall enter into it, and profane it'...

We see you aren't the first to have this question, but there is no need for concern since they are definitely not holy anymore.

Comment: Today is 11 Av, and it's interesting to note that Chatam Sofer ([Megilla 5a](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20210&st=&pgnum=92), and his responsa OC 33) explains that the reason we mourn primarily on 9 Av and not 10 Av is that the stuff that burned on 10 Av was not holy/significant since the Romans had already rendered it profane with their initial assault on 9 Av due to this rule.